# UnhandledPromiseRejection when I am trying to spy window object (jest + nuxt js)

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

I am using jest to spy window object to define my own window.scrollY value for my nuxt js component.

My jest codes:

```js
const winSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'window', 'get')
winSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
  scrollY: 200
}))
```

It works fine, but the error below is shown in terminal:

```
node:internal/process/promises:265
        triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
        ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an 
async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled 
with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "TypeError: Cannot read 
properties of undefined (reading 'get')".] {
```

What is the problem?

Can anyone help me to fix that?

Comment: Don't mock the whole window without a reason. If you need to mock scrollY, mock the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the original `window` properties in the `mockImplementation`:

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('reads scrollY', () => {
    const originalWindow = { ...window }
    const windowSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'window', 'get')
    windowSpy.mockImplementation(() => ({
      ...originalWindow, 
      scrollY: 200,
    }))
    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent)
    expect(wrapper.vm.top).toBe(200)
  })
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-jest-mock-window-prop?file=tests/unit/MyComponent.spec.js)